# I get an error "MemoryError" in Python. When I find association rules and keep in list()

Tags: python, list, data-mining, apriori

This code:

```
assoc_rules = apriori(records_mongo, min_support=0.5)
assoc_result = list(assoc_rules)
```

And when I run this code, Result show -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/mongodb_python/app2.py", line 54, in assoc_result = list(assoc_rules)
File "E:\mongodb_python\venv\lib\site-packages\apyori.py", line 288, in apriori
for support_record in support_records:
File "E:\mongodb_python\venv\lib\site-packages\apyori.py", line 203, in gen_support_records
candidates = _create_next_candidates(relations, length)
File "E:\mongodb_python\venv\lib\site-packages\apyori.py", line 157, in create_next_candidates
return list(tmp_next_candidates)
MemoryError
```

Comment: I understand your problem as i have the same, but you can describe a little bit better your problem instead of posting just a code error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apriori can be *very* memory intensive when you use a to low minimum support.

Also, **do not use apyori**. Last I checked it was just crappy code, incomplete and *not implementing the Apriori algorithm*. There are many bad libraries out there! Use pyfim instead.